# how add image/button next to last item in collection view in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, collectionview

i need your help i'm trying to make the following UI in xamarin forms.i want the Upload button or image at the end of list . i tried to use collection view with grid item layout .i'm able to show images like this but i can't add upload image at the end like the following . i tried to put upload image/button in the footer of collection view but it appears in bottom of the list not in next to last image . So is there any body who can help me or guide me to achieve this?
[Sample UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/686nb.png)

```
    <CollectionView x:Name="imgcollection" Margin="5" 
                                            BackgroundColor="Transparent" MinimumHeightRequest="15" HeightRequest="150"
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding ItemImages}"
                       >
                            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                                    <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                                     Span="{OnIdiom Tablet='6',Phone='4'}" HorizontalItemSpacing="1"
                                                 VerticalItemSpacing="2" >

                                    </GridItemsLayout>

                                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

                                <CollectionView.EmptyView>
                                    <StackLayout >
                                        <Image Source="picturemessage_2.png"  Aspect="AspectFill"
                                              HeightRequest="150" WidthRequest="150" HorizontalOptions="Start">

                                        </Image>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </CollectionView.EmptyView>

                            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ContentView Padding="5" Margin="30" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="150">

                                        <AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                                                <Image x:Name="imgview" Source="{Binding .}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFill"
                                                       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
                                                       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"/>
                                                <Image Source="moreoptionbtn.png" Aspect="AspectFill" IsVisible="{OnIdiom Tablet='True',Phone='False'}"
                                                       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,0.1,30,30" 
                                                       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"/>


                                            </AbsoluteLayout>

</ContentView>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>


                            </CollectionView>
```

C#

```
    private List<ImageSource> itemImages;
            public List<ImageSource> ItemImages
            {
                get { return itemImages; }
                set { itemImages = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("ItemImages");
                }
            }
 public ImageSource defultImage { get; set; } = "picturemessage_2.png";
            public bool Isadd { get; set; } = false;
           //
    void somefunction()
    {
         DetailPageViewModel.ItemImages.Add(picture);

                                DetailPageViewModel.ItemImages.OrderByDescending(s=>s);
                                var i = DetailPageViewModel.Isadd;
                                if (!i)
                                {
                                    DetailPageViewModel.ItemImages.Add(defultImage);
                                    DetailPageViewModel..Isadd = true;
                                }
    }
```

[image: output]
output

Comment: just make the upload image the last item in your ItemsSource

Comment: @Jason  i tried but it was not show in last , and i also tried to order the list but every time upload image comes in 2nd  number . i don't know why.

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: @Jason i update my question pleases check it again

Comment: first, `OrderByDescending` is a **function** that returns an ordered list.  Not sure if that is your actual problem or not - but it should be easy to inspect your data and verify that the last item in the list is what you think it is.

Comment: what is you suggestion , what should i have to do ?

Comment: yes, inspect your data to verify that it is actually sorted the way you think it is

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to click the Collectionview Item image to add image, but making the Upload image always stay on the last item, am I right?

If yes, I do one sample that you can take a look:

```
 <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemImages}" SelectionMode="Single">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="4" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.EmptyView>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Image
                        Aspect="AspectFill"
                        HeightRequest="150"
                        Source="image3.png"
                        WidthRequest="150" />
                </StackLayout>
            </CollectionView.EmptyView>

            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Image Margin="5" Source="{Binding .}">
                            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Image>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

Adding GestureRecognizers for Image control, then detecting if the last item image is clicked.

```
 public partial class Page6 : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<ImageSource> ItemImages { get; set; }
    public Page6()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ItemImages = new ObservableCollection<ImageSource>()
        {
            "a5.jpg","a6.jpg","a7.jpg","a8.jpg","a9.jpg","upload2.jpg"
        };

        this.BindingContext = this;
    }

    private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Image image = (Image)sender;                
        if (getimagesource(image.Source)!=null && getimagesource(image.Source) == "upload2.jpg")
        {
            int count = ItemImages.Count;
            ItemImages.Insert(count - 1, "a11.jpg");
        }
    }

    private string getimagesource(ImageSource img)
    {
        string path;
        if (img is Xamarin.Forms.FileImageSource)
        {
            Xamarin.Forms.FileImageSource objFileImageSource = (Xamarin.Forms.FileImageSource)img;
            //
            // Access the file that was specified:-
            path = objFileImageSource.File;
            return path;

        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

The screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `DataTemplateSelector` and map the last item to upload image or button

```cs
    public class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate DefaultTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate UploadTemplate { get; set; }

        protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
        {
            var currentItem = ((BindingItemType)item);


            var template = currentItem.Equals((container as CollectionView).ItemsSource.Cast<BindingItemType>().LastOrDefault()) ?  DefaultTemplate : UploadTemplate;
            return template;
        }
    }
```

```xml
 <ContentPage.Resources>
 <DataTemplate x:Name="default">
    <ContentView Padding="5" Margin="30" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="150">
        <AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Image x:Name="imgview" Source="{Binding .}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFill"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"/>
            <Image Source="moreoptionbtn.png" Aspect="AspectFill" IsVisible="{OnIdiom Tablet='True',Phone='False'}"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,0.1,30,30" 
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"/>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentView>
 </DataTemplate>
 <DataTemplate x:Name="uploadtemplate" >
    <Button Text="Upload" Clicked="UploadClicked"/>
 </DataTemplate>
 <local:MyTemplateSelector DefaultTemplate="{StaticResource default}" 
                           UploadTemplate="{StaticResource uploadtemplate}"
                           x:Name="templateselector" />
 </ContentPage.Resources>

 <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemImages}" SelectionMode="Single" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource templateselector}">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="4" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.EmptyView>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Image
                        Aspect="AspectFill"
                        HeightRequest="150"
                        Source="image3.png"
                        WidthRequest="150" />
                </StackLayout>
            </CollectionView.EmptyView>
        </CollectionView>
```

```cs
private void UploadClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{

//handle image upload and update the ItemsSource count.
}
```